# How to scrape .aspx

Tags: asp.net, web-scraping

http://fs.tblaw.com/Sales/PendingSales.aspx

[I want to see all the available data records at this web page by sending only a single HTTP request](http://fs.tblaw.com/Sales/PendingSales.aspx). But when I try, the response only returns the first 20.

So here's what I did:

1. Opened developer tools
2. Inspected network requests
3. On the target site, I manually set the "Records per page" menu value to 300

After doing that, I saw the parameter `ddlNumRows: 300` as a header in the POST request.

So I headed over to https://www.hurl.it to see if I could construct my own POST request as follows.

```
Destination: POST http://fs.tblaw.com/Sales/PendingSales.aspx
Parameters: ddlNumRows: 300
```

But, again, the server only returned the first ***20 records***.

### Question

> Does anyone have any suggestions how to get all the records from an HTTP server request without having to manually manipulate the form on the target page or click the paging buttons?

Comment: Have you tried with a lower value? Maybe 20 is the max value so it's ignoring anything beyond that.

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy: No. If you [inspect the page here](http://fs.tblaw.com/Sales/PendingSales.aspx): http://fs.tblaw.com/Sales/PendingSales.aspx, you will see 20 is the lowest menu option (and the default setting). 300 is the largest choice on the menu and I'm trying to set that value with an HTTP parameter in my request.

Comment: Ah ok, so 300 is a valid option

Comment: Well I captured the request with Fiddler and resent it and got 300 results This is from the response sent by Fiddler: <span id="lblListCount" class="pagertemplate">Files 1 - 300 (of 305 Total)</span> So I'd recommend to give it a go and play around with Composer

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy: What were the basics of your request? Was it POST? What parameters did you use? Did you set `ddlNumRows: 300`?